# Feedback for portfolio

Tags: internships, jobs

Hi!

I am a recent college graduate in electrical engineering with a concentration in audio engineering. I have been sound designing and composing for a while now and thus ready to apply for internships. I already applied for 30+ firms but barely got answers. Knowing that those firms get swamped with applications I thought having a strong portfolio might put me in a better position. My portfolio page shows some of my recent work but I cannot objectively judge it anymore. I therefore wanted ask you if you guys could provide me with some feedback:

[Portfolio](http://www.fabianluttenberger.com)

Thanks,
Fabian

Answer (score 1):

Forget about your portfolio. And don't just apply. Go out there and bother a couple of studios you really want to work in every single day until they give up and accept you as an intern. Once your foot is in the door it's much easier to stay in. Don't just call, show up. It's much harder for them to get rid of you this way. They'll start by letting you sit in on a couple of sessions, and if you play your cards right, you're in for the long run.

I got my first job through persistence, and every other intern that ended up working under my wing got in this way. Thought behind it being is if your persistent enough to persuade the employer to give you the job, your good enough to get any task done. Just one other piece of advice. Your opinion only starts to matter once trust has been established. Listen, don't talk.

Also, if you have a background in electrical engineering, it's always a plus for the studio. You can probably fix stuff without the studio having any downtime.

I hope you get your dreamjob.

Comment: So show up at their front door every day and ask if you can get an internship, even when they've said no a lot of times? Wouldn't that come come across as psychotic more than determined?
I don't think I could keep a conversation like that going for more than a few seconds... Can you elaborate a bit on what to do when you show up at their front door?

Answer (score 0):

Servus @Fabian,
Du bist in die "andere LA", oder?
In Louisiana gibt's ein Audio Post house...die haben an Contagion gearbeitet, Swelltone Labs. Ask them specific related questions, don't ask for work but for coffee, and keep emailing every month.

The second thing is, meet more directors than audio post houses, the directors will come back when they actually have a budget years later...

Or, even better, your degree in EE will not hurt your unsolicited applications at BMW Munich sound design, or Audi sound design in Ingolstadt. Bist du fit in Max/MSP?

Good luck, it's a jungle out there! 
mit freundlichen Grüßen,
Petr